# How to process dynamic IDs in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm a bit stumped on how to handle the following (the only solution I can think off the top of my head is to hand code every single such occurrence, but this is not scalable/practical since the page might be dynamic) - this is the original jQuery code which handles a form where the IDs are very simple (which works well):

```
$('#resultTable').on("click", "#frm", function() {                
       $('#updateButton').show();                                      
       $("#successStr").empty();                                            
});
```

But, what if I want to have multiple forms, each with their own ID (ie, #frm1, #frm2, etc), and dynamically have that ID suffix (1,2, etc) be part of the child/associated IDs?  Something like this (resultTable has multiple forms, each with an update button, etc):

```
$('#resultTable').on("click", "[id^='frm']", function() {                
       $('#updateButton'+XXX).show();                                      
       $("#successStr"+XXX).empty();                                            
});
```

Where XXX is the suffix ID number from the parent #frmID number (possibly to "capture" regex-style the number from the parent on()?)

Any hints on how to handle this would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Give the forms a shared `class` and attach the event handler using this `class` as the selector. Within the handler, `$(this)` will be the element that has received the event. To _link_ to other elements, give them a `data` attribute with something particular to each.

Comment: You can use a class on all the forms instead of IDs, and add data attributes . data-id(xxx)

Comment: If you show us the HTML markup it would be easier to give a better suggestion. Are those other elements within the `form`? If so, `$(this).find('some-selector-here')` will grab them. This _some-selector_ could be a shared `class`. So, no more `IDs` to care about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use frm_n for your forms and updateButton_n for your controls, i.e

frm_1 => updateButton_1, frm_2 => updateButton_2...

```
$('#resultTable').on("click", "[id^='frm_']", function() {                
       $('#updateButton_'+ $(this).attr("id").split("frm_")[1]).show();                                      
       $("#successStr_"+ $(this).attr("id").split("frm_")[1]).empty();                                            
});
```

Comment: would this work if there are a variable number of frms?  ie, today there might be 5, but six months from now there may be 200...  I cannot edit the code, it needs to dynamically handle it.

Comment: It should if all forms and the matching sub-elememnts follow the same "id" format.

Comment: It scares me the fact that a single change in the `ID` format would make the whole thing stop working. But then, the second solution I proposed would fall into the same situation.

Comment: Well, doesn't matter which option you go with, either same ID format, or using data- attributes, or class name dependence, it could all stop working one day if any of the format changes. So you need to pick the least likely one which will also give you the result you need now.

Comment: true - then this is probably the shortest solution, and also doesn't require me to change to class, etc.

Comment: @Henry No worries, see you when it breaks :)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show your `HTML` markup, but the solution below should work with little adjustment (to fit your current layout):

```js
$(function () {
    // When clicking any form with class = myForm
    $('#resultTable').on("click", ".myForm", function () {
        // Look for the button with class = myUpdateButton that's
        // within this form
        $('.myUpdateButton', $(this)).show();
      
        // Look for the element with class = mySuccessStr that's
        // within this form
        $('.mySuccessStr', $(this)).empty();
    });
});
```

```css
/* Just for this example */
.myForm {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

/* The buttons will be hidden at first */
.myUpdateButton {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="resultTable">
    <form class="myForm">
        <button class="myUpdateButton">Update</button>
        <span class="mySuccessStr">Success!</span>
    </form>
    <br />
    <form class="myForm">
        <button class="myUpdateButton">Update</button>
        <span class="mySuccessStr">Success!</span>
    </form>
</div>
```

Another solution is to rely on a `data` attribute:

```js
$(function () {
    // When clicking any form with class = myForm
    $('#resultTable').on("click", ".myForm", function () {
        var dataRel = $(this).data('rel');
      
        // Look for the button with class = myUpdateButton which
        // data-rel matches this form
        $('.myUpdateButton[data-rel=' + dataRel + ']').show();
      
        // Look for the element with class = mySuccessStr which
        // data-rel matches this form
        $('.mySuccessStr[data-rel=' + dataRel + ']').empty();
    });
});
```

```css
/* Just for this example */
.myForm {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

/* The buttons will be hidden at first */
.myUpdateButton {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="resultTable">
    <!-- Scenario where the elements are not within the form -->
    <form class="myForm" data-rel="f1">
        <br />
        <br />        
    </form>
    <br />
    <button class="myUpdateButton" data-rel="f1">Update</button>
    <span class="mySuccessStr" data-rel="f1">Success!</span>
    <br />
    <form class="myForm" data-rel="f2">
        <br />
        <br />        
    </form>
    <button class="myUpdateButton" data-rel="f2">Update</button>
    <span class="mySuccessStr" data-rel="f2">Success!</span>    
</div>
```

Comment: hmm, I like your first suggestion for it's simplicity (even though the programmer in me wants to use the data attribute...)

Let me give it a try and see - it looks like that should handle any number of forms dynamically.

Comment: Yes, you would be biased to go for the second one, but I think you should keep it as simple as possible. It would be way easier to maintain the code. :)

Comment: thanks to you too mate, you've shown me some additional stuff and reminded me about data atributes which I've never used before, but I just *know* will be using in the near future.

Ta!